# Why won't my Template's TextBox bind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to do some binding. For the most part, my MVVM application is working fine but I now want to use a Template. In this case, I'm using XCeed chart which expose a `SeriesTemplate`.

My code is:

```
  <UserControl
 xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" 
          x:Class="MyApp.AppUi.View.Graph.GraphView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:MyApp.AppUi.Converters" 
         >

<Grid>

    <Grid.Resources>

        <converter:MyIntConverter x:Key="MyIntConverter" />

        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyLabelTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource MyIntConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <!--give it a name,                             Bind to above,        choose property -->
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GraphDataCollection" Source="{Binding GraphDataList}" />


        <Style  x:Key="TextBoxTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="19" Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>

                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="12" Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" 
                         Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
                            <Rectangle RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" >
                                <Rectangle.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    </EventTrigger>

                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                                        <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.4" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </Rectangle.Triggers>

                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFffcf26" Offset="0.0" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFff7f04" Offset="1.0" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>


        <DataTemplate x:Key="SeriesTemplate">
            <Button>
                <StackPanel>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding GraphData.ShortDate}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTextStyle}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <GroupBox Header="{Binding Title}">
        <GroupBox.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0" >
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FF9d9d9d" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FF666666" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </GroupBox.Background>

        <xctk:Chart Height="400" Width="400" ShowLegend="False">

           <xctk:Chart.Areas>
            <xctk:Area >
                <xctk:Area.XAxis>

                    <xctk:Axis Title="Date" 
                                   GraduationMode="Manual" 
                                   LabelsType="DateTime"
                                   ScaleMode="Automatic"
                                   TitleMargin="10"
                                   AxisLabelsLayout="ShowAll"
                                   ShowArrow="False"
                                   ShowAxis="True"
                                   ShowGridLines="True"
                                   ShowTicks="True"
                                   ShowTickLabels="True"
                                   ShowAxisLabel="True"
                                   Reversed="False"
                                   />
                </xctk:Area.XAxis>
                <xctk:Area.YAxis>
                    <xctk:Axis Title="Google position"  
                                   ScaleMode="Manual"
                                   TitleMargin="10"
                                   AxisLabelsLayout="ShowAll"
                                   ShowArrow="False"
                                   ShowAxis="True"
                                   ShowGridLines="True"
                                   CustomRangeStart="1.00"
                                   CustomRangeEnd="111.00"
                                   ShowTicks="True"
                                   ShowTickLabels="True"
                                   ShowAxisLabel="True"
                                   Reversed="False" 
                                   LabelTemplate="{StaticResource MyLabelTemplate}"
                                   />
                </xctk:Area.YAxis>

                <xctk:Area.Series>
                        <xctk:Series DataPointsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GraphDataCollection}}"
                              Template="{StaticResource SeriesTemplate}"
                              ShowPointsInLegend="true">
                        <xctk:Series.DataPointBindings>
                            <xctk:BindingInfo PropertyName="Y">
                                <xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                                    <Binding Path="Position"/>
                                </xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                            </xctk:BindingInfo>
                            <xctk:BindingInfo PropertyName="X">
                                <xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                                        <Binding Path="Date"/>
                                </xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                            </xctk:BindingInfo>
                            <xctk:BindingInfo PropertyName="Label">
                                <xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                                    <Binding Path="ShortDate"/>
                                </xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                            </xctk:BindingInfo>
                        </xctk:Series.DataPointBindings>
                    </xctk:Series>
                </xctk:Area.Series>
            </xctk:Area>
        </xctk:Chart.Areas>
    </xctk:Chart>
    </GroupBox>


</Grid>
```

and my ViewModel

```
public class GraphViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public GraphViewModel(List<GraphData> data, string title )
    {
        this.GraphDataList = data;
        this.Title = title;
    }

    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public List<GraphData> GraphDataList { get; private set; }
}
```

And the DataContext is set in the Resource Dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:graphView="clr-namespace:MyApp.AppUi.View.Graph"
                xmlns:graphViewModel="clr-namespace:MyApp.AppUi.ViewModel.Graph"
                xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:MyApp.AppUi.Converters"
                >

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type graphViewModel:GraphViewModel}">
    <graphView:GraphView />
</DataTemplate>
```

The chart displays as desired but, the SeriesTemplate does not bind. There is an error message in the ouput window, which I understand what the message is saying, but not how to fix it.

The error message is

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ShortDate' property not found on 'object' ''ColumnPrimitiveInfo' (HashCode=39288004)'. BindingExpression:Path=ShortDate; DataItem='ColumnPrimitiveInfo' (HashCode=39288004); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

How do I get the binding to work for

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="SeriesTemplate">
            <Button x:Name="Bar">
                <StackPanel>                       
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GraphData.ShortDate}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTextStyle}" /> <!--THIS IS WHERE THE FAULT IS -->
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
```

XCeed have a [working demo](http://xceed.com/WPF_Toolkit_Demo.html) with source code, if you download the application, click on Charts -> Styling -> Column Series you can see that my code is very very similar. There's works, but mine does not and I can't see why. Please note, the graph itself displays, it's just the textbox is not showing. However, if I don't use binding, and just use `Text="SomeWords"` then it works fine

Comment: Where is your GraphData property? In your ViewModel or is it a xceed property? Could you give us a link to the documentation of the component you use? Couldn't find it on xceed website. http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedChart/

Comment: @nkoniishvt you can download their demo (which shows source code) from http://xceed.com/WPF_Toolkit_Demo.html - When it loads, under charts expand the Styling option and click on Column Series. From here, on the right you can see the XAML code (which works). I pretty much copied and pasted (it worked) then changed a few things and broke it. I can't see what I broke

Comment: Please post your ViewModel class and post the full xaml

Comment: @nkoniishvt, as requested, full code psoted

Comment: did you set the DataContext in the xaml backend code?

Comment: @nkoniishvt, no, in the ResourceDictionary (edited)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67141/discussion-between-nkoniishvt-and-mydaftquestions).

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of voodoo programming (where I just try different things at random) I found the solution.

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content.ShortDate}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTextStyle}" />
```

I think this is because of (see the Button Setter in code of OP)

```
 <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
```

Comment: What object did the "Content" property belong to?

Comment: Yes, I have seen this behavior before, ContentPresenter sometimes does not inherit its DataContext down its VisualTree. I have yet to find when or why exactly this happens. I'm glad it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SeriesTemplate">
        <Button>
            <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ShortDate}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTextStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the documentation here[on the XCeed documentation site](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfToolkit/#Chart%20control.html) it appears that you are adding an extra layer of indirection to the binding.  Try binding directly to the GraphDataList

```
<xctk:Series DataPointsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GraphDataList}}"
                          Template="{StaticResource SeriesTemplate}"
                          ShowPointsInLegend="true">
```

and then in the series

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SeriesTemplate">
    <Button>
        <StackPanel>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ShortDate}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxTextStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Sadly not, it needs this extra layer I think because the graph isn't part of the visual tree and as such, requires this addition to make the binding work